# In asp.net MVC, How to prevent webrequest to a particular controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have an e-commerce website on top of NopCommerce platform where there was an SMS resend OTP service written in MVC Controller (www.mysite.com/customer/resendotp).

A week ago someone started attacking this URL via different IP addresses to send OTP messages. So we renamed our MVC controller to newresendotp (www.mysite.com/customer/newresendotp).

Now unfortunately the attack is still going on to our old mvc controller. I want to prevent all requests to this MVC controller. How do I do that?

Comment: can't you just block that IP in the firewall?

Comment: @rmjoia As I said in the question itself that the requests are coming from 1000's of different IP addresses from various countries. So that is not possible.

Comment: `"I want to prevent all requests to this MVC controller."` - Remove the controller?  Remove the action method?  Make the action method private?

Comment: @milanm you can block a range.. don't they have anything in common? subnet?

Comment: @David, I already removed the controller. The problem is that the requests are still coming on our server for this controller and are thus triggering our Global Application error.

Comment: @rmjoia, There is nothing common as requests are coming from china, singapore, India, USA etc.

Comment: @milanm: If you want to prevent the requests from reaching the application then you need to do that outside of the application, such as at a firewall.  There's nothing the *application* can do to prevent itself from even *receiving* a request.  The application has no knowledge of a request until it's been received.

Comment: where your site is hosted? on shared server / dedicated or Cloud (AWS / Azure) ?

Comment: It is a dos attack. Blog the country of that ip if it is outside of your shop region. Suppose the attack come from the xyz country and your store is targeted for the abc country you need stop accessing of your site from the xyz country.

Answer (score 1):

How about blocking the request in IIS by adding the url to the old controller (www.mysite.com/customer/resendotp) as a Request Blocking rule?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template